# MS SQL - Grouping by Date and Count

Tags: sql-server

Hope you can guide me in this one.

Here is my scenario:

I have a table attendance for merchandisers.

So the merchandisers are required to submit inventory and delivery count every week. They can send everyday it depends, as long as they submit inventory or delivery count for the week.

Now, my requirement is to create an activity report.

[image: Activity Report]

As you can see in the screenshot, if a merchandiser is present, for example today,
and he sends delivery and inventory count today, the activity report should count and display it.

Here is my query:

```html
select a.TimeInDtRcvd,
        b.deliveryCount,
        c.inventoryCount
from    BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Attendance as a

       left join (select count(CreatedBy) as deliveryCount, CreatedBy, DtRcv
                  from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_H
                  group by CreatedBy, DtRcv) as b on a.CellNum = b.CreatedBy

     left join (select count(CreatedBy) as inventoryCount, CreatedBy, DtRcv
                from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H
                group by CreatedBy, DtRcv) as c on a.CellNum = c.CreatedBy

and  convert(date, a.TimeInDtRcvd) >= convert(date, '01/01/2018') and convert(date, a.TimeInDtRcvd) <= convert(date, '03/30/2018')
and  a.TimeIn is not null
and  a.TimeOut is not null

group by a.TimeInDtRcvd, b.deliveryCount, c.inventoryCount
```

Hope I explained myself clearly. If there are details that I can provide just say so and I will provide immediately. I am using MS SQL SERVER 2014. Thank you.

**EDIT**
I have solved it doing some trial and error and searching also.
Here is my new query:

```html
SELECT a.CellNum,
  e.LName + ' ' + e.FName as diser,
  cast(a.TimeInDtRcvd as date) as date,
  a.TimeIn as timeIn,
  a.TimeOut as timeOut,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.TransCtr) AS deliveryCount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.TransCtr) AS inventoryCount,
  COUNT(DISTINCT d.TransCtr) AS abisCount,
  overall_count = count(*) over()
from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Attendance as a

  left outer join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_H as b 
  ON b.CreatedBy = a.CellNum
  and cast(a.TimeInDtRcvd as date) = cast(b.DtRcv as date)


  left outer join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H as c 
  ON c.CreatedBy = a.CellNum

  and cast(a.TimeInDtRcvd as date) = cast(c.DtRcv as date)


  left outer join BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Abis_H as d 
  ON d.CreatedBy = a.CellNum
  and cast(a.TimeInDtRcvd as date) = cast(d.DtRcv as date)
    
    
   GROUP BY a.CellNum, 
        e.LName, 
        e.FName,
        a.TimeInDtRcvd,
        a.TimeIn,
        a.TimeOut
   ORDER BY diser asc, a.TimeInDtRcvd desc
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Paparazzi, I am  getting a different result. What happens it it displays only 1 count. for example there are 3 deliveried for today, it still shows only 1. Thankyou.

Comment: Post data to reproduce

Comment: And actual table schemas, please.

Comment: You said you would provide immediately and it has been 16 hour since you were asked for data to reproduce.

Comment: Hi @Paparazzi, I am sorry I won't be able to get back immediately, I am not at work. So I am not able to access the laptop. But I finally solved it.  I will edit my post to add the new query. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Messed up

You are doing a `count(CreatedBy)` and that is a `group by`
Surprise you get 1